# How to prevent rotating of a single element on page in WP8.1 universall app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, rotation, orientation, win-universal-app

I need to disable auto rotation (when device orientation changed) for one single element on page. I can disable it in all app by:

```
Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
```

But this is not what i want. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot disable rotate for an individual item.
If your application changes the screen orientation is rotated all the elements.

If only track event screen rotation, and resize this element in the opposite direction. But I don't think it's a good solution.

Comment: So how then system camera app works? It has preview area, which is not changing, but the other elements rotating at the same time?

Comment: Most likely the page layout is made for only one orientation. In fact, the layout of the page does not expand, and always stays in portrait.

And added event handling for rotation of the device. In the handler, turning individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the rotation event and transform(rotate) your element accordingly to current orientation. 
[Available orientations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.pageorientation(v=vs.105).aspx) 
[How to rotate element.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.rotatetransform.ASPx)